# Running Scheme in Jupyter (fka iPython)

Tags: scheme, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to run Scheme under Jupyter. The traditional cell magic approach, which works in other cases (using %%bash, %%latex or %%ruby), is not available.

Note: I am not interested in Scheme Calypso, which does not have the whole Scheme functionality. I just want to run my Scheme installation at /usr/bin/scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can't just run an arbitrary installation in Jupyter - you need a dedicated kernel. You've already ruled out the existing Scheme kernel so I don't know what you're expecting. Perhaps ou can write your own Scheme kernel?

Comment: It would be possible to wrap chez's or chicken's (etc) command-line program as a kernel. I tried to do racket once, but it wasn't yet possible to call as a command-line REPL.

Answer (score 0):

[Calysto Scheme](https://github.com/Calysto/calysto_scheme) has much of a full Scheme language specification. You can try it live here: https://jupyter.org/try

If you find it missing something that you would really like to have, please let us know!